# CSS pseudo class for label after being clicked

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I have the task of implementing a star review.

I assume that I need to set a rule on the label, since the `input`s are hidden. My question is, how can I give the stars a color of black even after being clicked. I know that the active pseudo-class only works when being clicked. Is there another pseudo-class for this? The goal of is to do this only using HTML/CSS.

```html
<div class="rating-stars" id="rating-stars-features">
  <input class="rating-radio visuallyhidden" type="radio" id="rating-features-1" value="1" />
  <input class="rating-radio visuallyhidden" type="radio" id="rating-features-2" value="2" />
  <input class="rating-radio visuallyhidden" type="radio" id="rating-features-3" value="3" />
  <label class="rating-star" for="rating-features-1">★</label>
  <label class="rating-star" for="rating-features-2">★</label>
  <label class="rating-star" for="rating-features-3">★</label>
</div>
```

Comment: Would help if you provided your CSS man, then it would save us both time

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve a HTML/CSS only star rating system that has good browser support by utilising the [CSS subsequent sibling selector `~`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/General_sibling_combinator) with flexbox `row-reverse` for left-to-right stars:

```css
.rating-stars {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row-reverse;
  width: fit-content;
}

.visuallyhidden {
  display: none;
}

.rating-radio:checked~.rating-star {
  color: gold;
}
```

```html
<div class="rating-stars" id="rating-stars-features">
  <input class="rating-radio visuallyhidden" type="radio" name="stars" id="rating-features-1" value="1" />
  <label class="rating-star" for="rating-features-1">★</label>
  <input class="rating-radio visuallyhidden" type="radio" name="stars" id="rating-features-2" value="2" />
  <label class="rating-star" for="rating-features-2">★</label>
  <input class="rating-radio visuallyhidden" type="radio" name="stars" id="rating-features-3" value="3" />
  <label class="rating-star" for="rating-features-3">★</label>
</div>
```